# How do I download boot camp assistant for windows 10

Tags: bootcamp, windows

I downloaded Windows 10 on my Mac today and now I am having some trouble with getting back to my mac software. i know a way is through boot camp but how do I download boot camp on windows 10.

Comment: The usual way to is use the macOS Boot Camp Assistant application to download the Boot Camp (Windows Support Software) files. Copy the files to a flash drive. Boot to Windows and run `setup.exe` on the flash drive.

Comment: By "getting back to my mac software." do you mean you are booted into Windows and don't know how to boot back to macOS? If so restart Windows and hold the option key, then choose what you want to boot from: Mac or Windows.

Comment: BootCamp Control Panel doesn't work for restarting if the host Mac is using APFS.  In that case, go to restart, and hold Alt/Option as soon as the computer chimes, and select your Mac HD.  It's best that you have a wired keyboard for this, as some wireless keyboards can't send the signal in time